# click on script generated div in selenium

Tags: dynamic, xpath, selenium

i am trying to click on a div like 
`[//div[24]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div]` .. although selenium verifies this div by `verifyElementPresent` and `xPath` is shown in `xPath` finder but click function of selenium does not click on it ..

selenium opens a page, i click on Customers link, script generates all the customers, then click on Details, script generates the detail page,. there i have to click on the div (Save button actually ) mentioned above ... any solution for this ???

Answer (score 1):

try `runScript` and fire the click event with javascript
e.g. if you have jQuery on the tested script

```
<!--fire awkward click event-->
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>$('.bo-selector').click();</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```